# PID controller value exceeds CmdMax/Min value

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I initialize my PID controller with specific max and min values:

`common::PID posPID;
posPID.Init(0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 200.0, 0.0);`

and when I do

`posPID.Update(desiredVel - _spindle.angVel, _stepTime);`

the value it returns can be negative or bigger than 200

Any hints what might be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13155/pid-controller-value-exceeds-cmdmax/min-value/) by [missx](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2419/missx/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I ripped this right from the source...

```
// Check the command limits
if (!ignition::math::equal(this->cmdMax, 0.0) && this->cmd > this->cmdMax)
    this->cmd = this->cmdMax;
if (!ignition::math::equal(this->cmdMin, 0.0) && this->cmd < this->cmdMin)
this->cmd = this->cmdMin;

return this->cmd;
```

Looks to me like you can't have a min of zero. It has to be something other than zero to be a min. This is definitely a bug, and should be addressed. For now, you could just set it to a small number like 0.001 and see if that works.

I can't immediately see why it's not respecting the 200 limit however. How much greater are we talking about? Can you add a smallest-possible-reproducible example?

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [missx](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2419/missx/) on 2016-04-26**:
yea, you're right. with minimum 0 it doesn't work. thanks!
and with maximum - my bad - output value has never reached it

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-05-09**:
You should consider making a pull request to allow a minimum of 0! It would a simple first-time contribution. We could require -inf/inf as the values if you want no min or max, and then remove that check for zero.